# How to connect remote powershell to Exchange server 2007 sp3?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, exchange-2007, exchange-2003

I have an Exchange environment with two servers - both are Exchange 2007 sp3.

Now I need to use remote PowerShell to pull some data from the servers.

How do I connect remote powershell from a client system to the Exchange server that is running Exchange 2007 sp3?

Answer (score 2):

Invoke-Command: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

From the help:

```
The Invoke-Command cmdlet runs commands on a local or remote computer and returns all output from the commands,
        including errors. With a single Invoke-Command command, you can run commands on multiple computers.

        To run a single command on a remote computer, use the ComputerName parameter. To run a series of related commands
        that share data, use the New-PSSession cmdlet to create a PSSession (a persistent connection) on the remote
        computer, and then use the Session parameter of Invoke-Command to run the command in the PSSession. To run a
        command in a disconnected session, use the InDisconnectedSession parameter. To run a command in a background job,
        use the AsJob parameter.

        You can also use Invoke-Command on a local computer to evaluate or run a string in a script block as a command.
        Windows PowerShell converts the script block to a command and runs the command immediately in the current scope,
        instead of just echoing the string at the command line.

        To start an interactive session with a remote computer, use the Enter-PSSession cmdlet. To establish a persistent
        connection to a remote computer, use the New-PSSession cmdlet.

        Before using Invoke-Command to run commands on a remote computer, read about_Remote
        (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135182).
```

Comment: Can I use this to connect to Exchange 2007 sp3? And canb I use this command in Powershell v2.0?

Comment: Yes to both questions.